# How to interrupt await'ing in a loop

Tags: asynchronous, rust

Consider this function receiving datagrams from UDP socket:

```
async fn recv_multiple(socket: &async_std::net::UdpSocket) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];
    let mut v = vec![];

    while let Ok((amt, _src)) = socket.recv_from(&mut buf).await {
        v.push(String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf[..amt]).to_string());
    }

    v
}
```

And then it is executed for example like this:

```
let fut = recv_multiple(&socket);
async_std::task::block_on(fut);
```

How to add timeout functionality so that after exactly 1 minute a `Vec<String>` (empty or not) is returned from `recv_multiple`? I need to collect incoming datagrams for a minute and then return what was captured during that time. Please note that I don't need to timeout a single `recv_from` operation because datagrams can appear very often and the function will never timeout.

I've found a couple of partial solutions but they don't fit well:

1. [`async_std::future::timeout`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/future/fn.timeout.html) times out a `Future` but partially filled `Vec` is discarded and only `Err` is returned
2. [`async_std::future::Future::timeout`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/future/trait.Future.html#method.timeout) same story, partial output is discarded

As I see it I should pass some kind of a "timeout" `Future` inside this function and in `while let` I have to `await` on both socket and "timeout" `Future`. Then if socket fires we proceed but if "timeout" fires then we return from the function. But I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timeouting on `recv_multiple` you can [timeout](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/io/fn.timeout.html) on `socket.recv_from` inside `recv_multiple`. It'll require to recalculate remaining time after each iteration. And when remaining time is 0 then you can return your `Vec<_>`.